# Find number of common elements in given vectors from an array of vectors

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a given array of vectors of different sizes and the total number of elements in all vectors won't exceed 10<sup>4</sup>. Each vector contains at least 1 and at most 10<sup>4</sup> unique integers, each integer being in the range 1 to 10<sup>4</sup>.

There will be 10<sup>5</sup> queries where each query asks to find the number of common integers in some given vectors (at most 4).

For example:
4 vectors:

```
1 2 5
3 5 6
1 3 6
6 7
```

1 Query:

```
2 3 (vectors indexed 2 and 3)
```

Ans:

```
2 (2 common integers {3,6})
```

I am unable to come up with an efficient solution for this problem. What algorithm / data structure will be most suitable for this problem? Any references would be very helpful.

**EDIT**: No integer will occur in more than 4 vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vectors are sorted you can do that. You start from the largest of all first vector's element (as there cannot be a common element before) and you try to find the smallest largest common element. If there is one you start over from the remaining parts of the vectors. Otherwise you just look at the next plausible candidate.

Let `v1, .., v4` denote the four choosen vector.

```
Let i1=i2=i3=i4=0
While (i1 < v1.length, i2 <v2.length, i3 < v3.length, i4 < v4.length)
    Let X = max(v1[i1],v2[i2],v3[i3],v4[i4])
    Increase i1, i2, i3, i4 such that v1[i1]>=X, v2[i2]>=X, v3[i3]>=X, v4[i4]>=X
    If v1[i1]=v2[i2]=v3[i3]=v4[i4]
        count++
        i1++
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the vectors in a set data structure that allows you to do a lookup in O(1) and iterate over all the elements in O(N).

For each query just iterate over the elements in one of the vectors and for each of those elements, check if it exists in the other vector.

Comment: That in the worst case will take O(n) time per query which is quite expensive

Comment: Yes, but isn't the accepted answer also O(N) just with O(N*logN) preprocessing instead of here O(N) preprocessing, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: You are right (given the numbers, pre-processing can however most likely be neglected -- and I don't know which of our answers is faster then).